# How many males and females attend an event

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The amount of attendees to an event follows a Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda$. The probability of an attendee being male is $p$ and being female is $1-p$. Show that the random variables $M=$ 'amount of male attendees' and $F=$ 'amount of female attendees' follow Poisson distributions with parameters $\lambda p$ and $\lambda(1-p)$ respectively.

So far I have:

Let $A=$'number of attendees'

$$P(M=k)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty P(M=k|A=i)P(A=i)=\sum\limits_{i=k}^\infty \binom{i}{k}p^k(1-p)^{i-k}\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^i}{i!}=$$ $$=\frac{e^{-\lambda}(\lambda p)^k}{k!}\sum\limits_{i=k}^\infty \frac{\lambda^{i-k}}{(i-k)!}(1-p)^{i-k} =\frac{e^{-\lambda}(\lambda p)^k}{k!}\sum\limits_{j=0}^\infty \frac{\lambda^{j}}{j!}(1-p)^{j}$$

But I have no idea how to prove that this equals $\frac{e^{-\lambda p}(\lambda p)^k}{k!}$ or if this is the right approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $\sum_{j=0}^\infty \lambda^j (1-p)^j/j!$ is a very familiar Taylor series in $x = \lambda(1-p)$.

Comment: Oh! thanks. how did I miss that?

Answer (score 0):

Note that: $$\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{(\lambda(1-p))^j}{j!}=e^{\lambda(1-p)}$$

Comment: Thanks! Don't know why I keep missing this things...